# Returning object with lowest double field

Tags: java, object, min

I have an object Link which takes the following parameters:

Link(Airport Airport1, Airport Airport2, double distance)

I have a list of these Link objects, and I wish to return the one with the lowest distance. How would I iterate through a list in order to do this?

The code I have been trying:

```
double minLinkDistance = 1000;

Link minLink = null

for(Link l : links) {
    if(minLinkDistance > l.getDistance()) {
        minLinkDistance = l.getDistance();
        minLink = l;
        }
    }
```

However I dont want to set the bounds myself, (i.e. a distance of 1000) how would I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You can rely on the fact that `minLink` is initially not set. Note that you don't need to store the `minLinkDistance` value if all you need to do is to find the link with the minimum distance:

```
Link minLink = null;
for(Link l : links) {
    if (minLink == null || l.getDistance() < minLink.getDistance()) {
        minLink = l;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize the minLink and min distance to the first element of the list:

```
double minLinkDistance = links.get(0).getDistance();

Link minLink = links.get(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace 1000 with [`Double.MAX_VALUE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#MAX_VALUE). When going through your distances, this should ensure that the distance will be replaced with one you currently have.

Answer (score 0):

You can have to solutions:

1) Replace 1000 with `Double.MAX_VALUE`

2) Replace the for loop with the following:

```
for (int i = 0; i < links.size(); i++) {
    Link l = links.get(i);
    if (i == 0 || minLinkDistance > l.getDistance()) {
        minLinkDistance = l.getDistance();
        minLink = l;
    }
}
```

In this second solution you will test for the first element and put him as the current minimum distance because it is the first element.